# Why my input is showing one thread executing after another thread, not at the same time?

Tags: java, multithreading

I researched the concept of a thread and saw that it is to have code run in two processes at the same time. Heres my code though

```
public class Connor extends Thread{

    public void run() {
        for(int i=0; i< 10; i ++){
            System.out.println("Hello " + i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Connor runner1 = new Connor();
        Connor runner2 = new Connor();
        runner1.start();
        runner2.start();
    }
}
```

And my output https://i.stack.imgur.com/7reYP.jpg

It seems like the two threads  do start off at the same time(separate processes, as indicated by the two leading 0s) but one executes (1-9) and then the other executes (1-9). Arent they suppose to interweave as well (1,1,2,2,...) bc the threads both print to the console. I researched and saw that start is the right method to use as it tells the thread class to execute the run method in another thread? Can anyone explain why im getting this output?

Comment: Please review your code.

Comment: paste exact code, this isn't going to compile

Comment: Your outputs don't *have* to interleave. They just *can*. That's the best part about race conditions -- unpredictable results.

Comment: There is almost never a reason to extend `Thread`. Instead you should implement a `Runnable` and pass that to the constructor of the `Thread`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you have ten errands you need to do and your sister has ten errands she needs to do, and you only have one car. Do you bring the car back after each errand and switch drivers? Of course not. That would be absurdly inefficient. Each thread basically just needs the output stream. So it would be absurd to interleave them tightly.

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks fine. I guess that your threads do not run in parallel just because they terminate to fast. Change the loop limit from 10 to 1000 and you will see the effect.

Starting thread itself is relatively heavy operation. You code starts the first thread and then the second one. The first thread once started terminates before the second thread got a chance to start executing its business logic.

Answer (score 2):

In case of Multi-threading there is no guarantee that which thread is allocated for what time to run by the processor and in that case the result is unpredictable and will generate different output for each run.

If you are looking for desired output then you need synchronization block. using `wait` and `notify` you can achieve it easily.

Please have a look at below Lesson directly from *Oracle official site*:

- [Lesson: Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) to read more about concurrency.
- [Chapter 17. Threads and Locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html) to read more about thread, locks and synchronization.

**Note:** `wait` & `notify` must be called inside the `synchronized` block and can call on the same object on which it is synchronized.

Sample code: (*read inline comments*)

```
public class Connor extends Thread {

    private static Connor runner1 = new Connor();
    private static Connor runner2 = new Connor();

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Hello " + i);

            // wake up another thread to come out from wait state
            if (runner1 == this) {
                // wake up runner2
                synchronized (runner2) {
                    runner2.notify();
                }
            } else {
                // wake up runner1
                synchronized (runner1) {
                    runner1.notify();
                }
            }

            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    // say current thread to wait until notify by another thread
                    this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runner1.start();
        runner2.start();
    }
}
```

output:

```
Hello 0
Hello 0
Hello 1
Hello 1
Hello 2
Hello 2
Hello 3
Hello 3
Hello 4
Hello 4
Hello 5
Hello 5
Hello 6
Hello 6
Hello 7
Hello 7
Hello 8
Hello 8
Hello 9
Hello 9
```

Comment: @TheLostMind - One could argue that the OP's real problem is trying to do this in the first place.

Comment: @StephenC - I don't disagree... :).

Answer (score 0):

> Why my input is showing one thread executing after another thread, not at the same time?

The general explanation is that Thread scheduling is unpredictable.  Interleaving *may* happen ... or it *may not*.  That is fundamental to Java threading.  (And indeed to threading in most other languages.)

If you need thread execution to interleave in an entirely predictable way, you need to implement some kind of hand-shake mechanism, where one thread waits for another one to do something, and do on.  But that is complicated, and typically defeats the purpose of using threading.

FWIW: @Braj's answer shows how you might implement strict interleaving.  However note that this effectively means that only one thread is going to execute at a time.  In addition, the waiting / notifying is going to lead to a lot of work for the thread scheduler ... some that the application will run significantly slower than if you had just done the work on one thread.

---

In this particular example, there are two issues that combine to make any short term interleaving unlikely:

1. Creating a new native thread in Java is relatively expensive, because it typically entails requesting a memory block from the OS to house the thread stack.  That in turn entails the OS "messing around" with page tables, zeroing a memory block and so on.
2. Native thread scheduling is implemented by the operating system, and it operates at a fairly coarse-grained level ... because that is the most efficient way to operate from the perspective of a typical application.  (Switching thread "contexts" in a PC-class machine is relatively expensive operation, and the thread scheduler itself potentially has work to do.)

In your example, the chances are that the first thread can say "hello" ten times before the second thread is ready to be scheduled.